# What's the best way to update some properties of an object immutably in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

Say we have an object like:

```
const obj = {
  foo: {
    a: { type: 'foo', baz: 1 },
    b: { type: 'bar', baz: 2 },
    c: { type: 'foo', baz: 3 }
  }
}
```

Now I want to update all properties' `baz` to `5` if the `type` of the property in `foo` is `foo`. And I would like to modify it in an immutable way, that means it would not modify the origin object but returns a new object.

Comment: You mean you want to make a new `{ type: 'foo': baz: 5}` object, or you want a whole new `obj` object?

Comment: you could deep copy `obj` then make the changes to the copy

Comment: Yes, @JaromandaX! But deep copy(like `_.deepClone`) might have performance problem if the object was a big object. Is there any idea without deep copy?

Comment: well, if you want `obj` to be immutable, then you'll **have** to deep-copy - depends on which part you are referring to as immutable I guess

Comment: *"might have performance problem"* - Either you want a deep copy or you don't. You can't get a new object without copying the old one. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to show the desired output more clearly.

Comment: Nope, @Barmar. What I want is what Jaromada said.

Comment: Use [functional lenses](https://github.com/DrBoolean/lenses).

Comment: @JaromandaX But you can share references between nested immutable `Object`s and thus your deep copy has to be only partially deep. In the OP's example, for instance, you could share `{ type: 'bar', baz: 2 }`. This technique is known as structural sharing.

Comment: If you want something simple use David JorHpan's answer. If you want something performant, use immutable.js or mori. It's pretty well that cut and dried.

Answer (score 1):

I normally write `Object.create()` for shallow copy ,but deep copy (nested object) I do with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nestedObject))`

```
const obj = {
  foo: {
    a: { type: 'foo', baz: 1 },
    b: { type: 'bar', baz: 2 },
    c: { type: 'foo', baz: 3 }
  }
}
var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

for(var i in temp.foo) {
  if(temp.foo[i].type == "foo") {
    temp.foo[i].baz = 5;
  }
}
console.log(temp);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Might note that your method only works if all of the values are valid JSON values... exceptions being Dates, functions, DOM nodes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` is perfect for this, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

And you can use it like this :

```
Object.assign(
    {},
    obj,
    {
        foo: {
            a: {
                baz: obj.foo.a.type === 'foo' ? 5 : obj.foo.a
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Object.entries()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, spread element, computed property, `Object.assign()`

```js
const obj = {
  foo: {
    a: { type: 'foo', baz: 1 },
    b: { type: 'bar', baz: 2 },
    c: { type: 'foo', baz: 3 }
  }
}

let key = Object.keys(obj).pop();

let res = {[key]: Object.assign({},
          ...Object.entries(obj[key])
          .map(([prop, {type,baz}]) => 
            ({[prop]: {type,baz:type === "foo" ? 5 : baz}})
          ))};
  
console.log(res, obj);
```